# Using an offset for a date that isn't today

Tags: java, date, calendar

I did a lot of searches trying to find this solution. Messing with dates in Java gives me a headache. Most of the results I found were using math to find a previous date or about finding a date offset from today's date. I really needed something from a predefined date (not today). I messed with a lot of classes and code before finding what I needed.

This is also my first post here. I'm a veteran lurker. I hope this saves someone the time I took to find this.

Submit date Dec 2, 2014 and find the date from the week before.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class FilenameDateFormat {

    SimpleDateFormat fileDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        new FilenameDateFormat("20141202", -7);
    }

    public FilenameDateFormat(String dateArg, int offsetDays) throws ParseException {

        Date fileDate = fileDateFormat.parse(dateArg);
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(fileDate);

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, offsetDays);

        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

RESULT
Tue Nov 25 00:00:00 EST 2014

Comment: Thanks for posting, but you should have asked a question and then _answered_ it yourself.  Or better yet just ask the question and maybe see if you get any other answers.

Comment: @Sherlock (A) FYI, the old [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. (B) Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone which may lead to unexpected/incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use new java.time api ? This could be easily acomplished in java8.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "20141202" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE 
).minusWeeks( 1 )
```

> 2014-11-25

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> Messing with dates in Java gives me a headache.

Date-time work in general is tricky, slippery, elusive.

And using the troublesome old date-time classes (`java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, etc.) makes the work all the more difficult. Those old classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

> Submit date Dec 2, 2014

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Your input string happens to be in the “basic” version of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The canonical version includes hyphens, `2014-12-02`, while the “basic” version minimizes the use of separators, `20141202`. I strongly suggest using the fuller version when possible to improve readability and reduce ambiguity/confusion.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class includes a pre-defined formatting pattern for your input, [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String input = "20141202" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

In real code, trap for the `DateTimeParseException` being thrown because of bad input.

```
String input = "20141202" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;
LocalDate ld = null;
try{
   ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …  // Handle error because of bad input.
}
```

## Subtracting a week

> find the date from the week before

Subtract a week. Note that java.time uses immutable objects. So rather than alter (mutate) the values in an object, we generate a new and separate object based on the original’s values.

```
LocalDate oneWeekAgo = ld.minusWeeks( 1 );
```

> input: 20141202
>
> ld.toString(): 2014-12-02
>
> oneWeekAgo.toString(): 2014-11-25

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/mk4j3G).

If you want a String in the same format as the input, use the same formatter seen above.

```
String output = oneWeekAgo.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE );
```

> 20141125

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).